# display error message beside (on the right side) a text box when a validation error is made

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am trying to get my error message to display on the right side of my input text box. At the moment it appears under it.

looks like this at the moment:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k5hvzcvz446qgse/Login.PNG?dl=0

code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LoginStudentNumber, "LoginStudentNumber", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Username", value="" })
<div style="color: black; font-weight: bold;">@ViewBag.InvalidID</div>
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LoginPassword, "LoginPassword", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password", type="password" })
<div style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"> @ViewBag.InvalidPassword </div>
<input type="submit" id="button" class="login-button" value="Login" />
```

Comment: So, what the problem? Just put it on the right side of input text box

Comment: yes i did, it still appears under by default.

Comment: I assume you mean the `@ViewBag.InvalidID` and `@ViewBag.InvalidPassword`? (why are you not using `ValidationMessageFor()`?). They are inside `<div>` elements so unless you style them as `display: inline-block` they will be on a new line. But you can always use a `<span>` instead

Comment: And why are you using `TextBoxFor()` and then setting the `type="password"` attribute (instead of `PasswordFor()`) and why are you trying to set the `value` attribute and what do you think the second parameter (`"LoginStudentNumber"`) is doing?. Suggest you go to the MVC site and learn the basics of creating a view.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @stephen muecke the standard way to use validation is `ValidationMessageFor()` and you need to use `DataAnnotations`  for this purpose but just for your specific question

You can add use a `table` ,so that you would be able to wrap your `textbox` and `validation` message in a `td` and then
Try to use `span` instead of `div`

```
<span style="color: black; font-weight: bold;">@ViewBag.InvalidID</span>
```